# Robot localization fusing wheel and visual odometry

Tags: ros, navigation, visual-odometry, rtabmap-odometry, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I'm trying to fuse whell and visual odometry in robot_localization package. But I get insufficiently accurate data on output. The robot is lost more strongly, than at use only a wheel odometry. It is especially noticeable that the robot is lost when it approaches very close to the wall.
I'm using kinect and rtab_map for visual odometry.

This is my launch file to robot_localization.

```
<remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odom" />


  <param name="frequency" value="20"/>  

  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>  

  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>
  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="odom_base"/>
   <param name="odom1" value="odom_visual"/>

  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true, true, false,  
                                  false, false, true, 
                                  false, false, false,   
                                  false, false, true,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="odom1_config">[false, false, false, 
                                  false, false, false, 
                                  true, true, false,   
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>
 <param name="odom1_differential" value="false"/>

  <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
<param name="odom1_relative" value="false"/>

  <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>

  <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
  <param name="debug_out_file"  value="debug_ukf_localization.txt"/>

  <param name="alpha" value="0.001"/> 
  <param name="kappa" value="0"/> 
  <param name="beta" value="2"/>
</node>
```

What is right way to fuse whell and visual odoms? How should I set  and ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282900/robot-localization-fusing-wheel-and-visual-odometry/) by [Andrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/32433/andrey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reasons for you problem might be:

1- you need to adjust the process noise covariance from the parameter file because the model is not describing the kinematics accurately.

2- the covariances you are using for each odometry is not precise and therefore the ekf can diverge.

As for how you should set the config parameter of each odometry, this depends on the output of these odometries.

i understand from your launch file is that your wheel odometry gives the pose [x, y, yaw] and also yaw angular velocity. if this is not true adjust your file.

The same for visual odometry, in your file you configured it to give you [vx, vy] if this is not correct adjust your file given that the config parameter is arranged as follows:

[x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az]

---

Originally posted by [Mostafa Osman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33507/mostafa-osman/) with karma: 30 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1